# Sass / Compass CSS3 mixins not working

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am just beginning with sass and compass and stuff and writing my own mixins works well, etc... so SASS seems to be working fine.

Discovering about compass sounded very great at first, but i have the problem, that the default CSS3-Supported-Mixins just won't work.

GEM Version: 1.8.24

SASS Version: 3.1.19

COMPASS Version: 0.12.1

My screen.scss

```
@import "compass/reset";

.bam {
  @include border-radius(5px);
}
```

I created the project via `compass create myProject`. Followed by using `cd myProject`. Followed by `compass watch`.

Writing the above mentioned `.scss` i get the following error message

```
Change detected at $time to: screen.scss
error sass/screen.scss <Line 11: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.> overwrite stylesheets/screen.css
```

The compass manual doesn't state anything about more configuration needed. So i am kind of stuck here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Solution**

Even though thinking i did so previously in a test, too, the solution is to actually INCLUDE the required Compass "class" via `@import "compass/css3"`

Comment: post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that i did not import the compass/css3 dependency.
This is done by adding `@import "compass/css3"` to the .scss-file

Comment: my compass mixins are not working even after using this import

Comment: looks like a different issue then @AdityaSanghi - I suggest opening a new question.